# Can dumb-phones be turned into bugs?

Tags: phone

Is it possible for an advanced attacker to use a dumb-phone (such as, say, Nokia 105) to spy on its owner through the microphone?

Comment: Depends on how dumb.  Old-fashioned POTS phones can't, because the hook switch physically disconnects the speaker and microphone from the phone line.

Comment: Sure, they can call their other phone from it, and then put it in your pocket, without hanging up. Now they can hear what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but not practical.

### Planting

Physical access would probably be necessary to flash data collection->exfiltration software onto the phone, or there would have to be a remote attack available (which is possible however it may require user interaction, perhaps social engineering of some sort - zero-clicks are rare). This is probably the most difficult part of designing malware for this particular target.

### Possible Design

Software/firmware hooking all microphone data at all times and sending it wirelessly to a certain location/number (real-time or in chunks).

### Detection

There may also be interference with the functionality of the phone (in particular, battery life), and if software isn't written to deal with edge cases, unexpected behavior (such as calls not working) is likely.

Answer (score -6):

technically, yes it's possible

but you'd have to write all the software yourself or pay some sketchy black hats to do it

or, like, be the NSA, man.

Comment: Can you add more detail on how it would technically be done?

Comment: This "answer" is worthless. It has no actual information, no technical details, no references...